# Google plus integration in webview

Tags: android, android-intent, google-plus

Currently I integrated google plus in android. But it works using native google plus app. 
I used this to create a sample project.
https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/android

But I want to let user login using WebView and not the google plus native app. 
Is there a way to user do google+ integration in WebView in android ?

Thanks In advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you'll essentially need to grab an access token that you can use to perform authenticated  actions on behalf of the user.

For a purely client-side flow, you have three options:

- HTML button
- Button rendered with JavaScript
- Initiate the sign-in flow with JavaScript

For detailed web guides about these and other flows involving servers, checkout [Google's web sign-in help page](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/).

There is also a nice basic tutorial for [Google+ sign-in via Android WebView](http://www.riskcompletefailure.com/2013/12/google-sign-in-on-android-chromium.html) by Ian Barber.

If you need to use more Google+ functionality beyond login, consider looking up the Google+ JavaScript API.